# Certain characters failing to be inserted into database

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding, special-characters

I have multi language characters that are being inserted into a varchar column of a MySQL MyISAM table.

One particular character, and I'm sure there are others is failing to be inserted:

�

What is this character and how can I convert this character without affecting the entire word. The server side code that can be used to manipulate these words is php.

Examples of actual words including this symbol are as follows:

portugu�s

espa�a

etc

What is the best way to insert these words correctly?

Comment: That's just the replacement character. A character encoding mismatch has occurred at some point. Where exactly do you see this character? After getting submitted data, but before inserting in DB using PHP? Or after inserting in DB using DB admin tool? Or after retrieving from DB using PHP but before sending to webbrowser? Or after displaying data in HTML using webbrowser?

Comment: Before inserting into the DB. I will need to look through the code base to see if the data being inserted has already been manipulated.

Comment: How are you viewing/displaying it? By echoing it back to the browser? If so, did you set the right response encoding by `header('Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8')`?

Comment: I've set the encoding to utf-8 before there is any output, using ini_set('default_charset', 'utf-8'); The data is being received from a feed and it comes through as ê or (Português) absolutely fine. Once the XML feed has been processed through getXMLObject the word gets converted to Portugu�s.

Comment: Not getXMLObject - i mean simplexml_load_string()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting charactset issues right can be a bit of a mission. Have a look at this blog post I wrote a couple of weeks ago which should cover this off. Post back here if you're still having problems.

[How to Avoid Character Encoding Problems in PHP](http://webmonkeyuk.wordpress.com/2011/04/23/how-to-avoid-character-encoding-problems-in-php/)

Comment: Your mention at the end "PHP string functions are not unicode aware" was my issue. Thanks for the link.